# Sum of 3 UITextField?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, xcode9

https://ibb.co/nH38wG

Why the result is 123 and not 6 ?

Anyone is able to elaborate and explain it to me please?

Comment: `code`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    var textField1 : UITextField!
    var textField2 : UITextField!
    var textField3 : UITextField!
    var label : UILabel!
    let str : String = "You have entered:"`code`

Comment: concatenating strings and summarising numeric values are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the text (`String`) values to each other in the label text. You should do this instead:

```
guard let num1 = Int(textField1.text),
    let num2 = Int(textField2.text),
    let num3 = Int(textField3.text) else {
    return
}

let sum = num1 + num2 + num3
label.text = str+sum
```

Comment: Try it like that:) i got...     Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

Comment: textField.text is not Int, it is a String value, this is why you cannot add them mathematically to each other, you can add them beside each other in a String. So we converted those strings to Integers, then we added them mathematically to each other.

Comment: Int(String) returns an Int? (optional), you need to add write Int(textField.text!)! for each of the fields, to force unwrap the optional

Answer (score 0):

You are "summing" strings. "1"+"2"+"3"="123".
Convert it to a number: Int("1")+Int("2")+Int("3")=6.

```
label.text = str + Int(textField1.text!)! + Int(textField2.text!)! + Int(textField3.text!)!
```